# Android layout: How to stop "wrap_content" from growing beyond minHeight of another layout?

Tags: android, layout

I tried many combinations of various layout attributes but I can't get it to work like I want it to.

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/signature_cntSummary"
    android:layout_below="@+id/signature_cntHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/signature_cntInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="200dp">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now what I like to achieve is that "signature_cntInput" should be at least 200dp in height but - if possible - should fill up the probably free screen space left by the "signature_cntSummary" layout if the content of that upper layout isn't consuming all the space.
If the first layout has too much content it should not push the second layout out of the screen but be scrollable so that the bottom layout can be 200dp in height.

Maybe these pictures make it clearer:

[Image: bottom layout takes remaining space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAQfj.png)

[Image: bottom layout is forced to min height and upper layout content becomes scrollable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpxQY.png)

How do I do that? Is it even possible? I'm running out of ideas ...

André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Layout Code Here]

The above layout sample might help you.

Comment: Thank you! 
But not quite what I intended to achieve ... so I edited my question to hopefully clarify that point. The bottom layout should stay where it is on the screen. Just expanding to the top if there is less content in the upper layout or shrink in height to a minimum of 200dp if there is more / too much content in the upper layout. That upper layout becomes scrollable then.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your point.Now I think what you want may not be achieved by pure xml code.I suggest that you override onMeasure to control the height of the upper layout,making sure that the screen has at least 200dp space for the lower layout.

Comment: You are right and I basically did what you suggested:

`@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = Math.max(height - height / 2, height / 2);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(newHeight, mode));
    }`